# Show $r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4<2r$

Tags: geometry

There are acute triangle $ABC$. $D$ is a foot of perpendicular in $AB$ from $C$,$E$ is a foot of perpendicular in $BC$ from $A$,$F$ is a foot of perpendicular in $AC$ from $B$.
Let  triangle $ADF$'s inscribed circle's radius is $r_1$,triangle $DBE$'s inscribed circle's radius is $r_2$,triangle $CEF$'s inscribed circle's radius is $r_3$,triangle $DEF$'s inscribed circle's radius is $r_4$,triangle $ABC$'s inscribed circle's radius is $r$, Show $r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4<2r$

Comment: Diagrams, diagrams, diagrams...Many geometry questions without a diagram are just too weary to deal with .

Comment: That ADF's = r1 is natural.

Comment: This title is only informative for you.